# Jodit, function to always insert html at the start of the editor (force it to be added to the beginning of the editor)

Tags: insert, move, mouse-cursor, jodit

I'm using Jodit and thanks to the online documentation, I managed to create a custom button to insert custom html by adding an additional control.

```
var editor = Jodit.make('#investigation', {
  buttons: [
    'insertDate'
  ],
  controls: {
    insertDate: {
      name: 'insertDate',
      iconURL: '../../../images/icons/jodit/calendar.png',
      exec: function (editor) {
         editor.s.insertHTML("<hr /><b>"+new Date().toDateString()+"</b><br />start typing here<br />");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When pushing the button, it fires the insertHTML() method and the html is perfectly added.

The problem is that it inserts the html at the current position of the cursor, which is of course expected behaviour. But I would like to insert the new html always at the beginning of the editor, so always as the first text in the editor.
I cannot find a method to move the cursor to the start of the editor.
Unfortunately the insertHTML() method doesn't allow to say where to insert the html (current position, start, end).

Thank you in advance for any support.

I tried the existing methods like insertCursorAtPoint(), setCursorAfter(), setCursorBefore(), setCursorIn() but was not able to get it to work. There are also no examples in the documentation how to use it.

Comment: Having the same issue, I tried insertCursorAtPoint(0,0) and got nothing